# Neo4jRepository saves empty node from Kotlin data class

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j, neo4j-ogm

I have a Kotlin data class node for Neo4j nodes:

```
@NodeEntity
data class MyNode (
    @Id @GeneratedValue var dbId: Long? = null,
    @Index(unique = true) val name: String,
    val description: String
)
```

and a Spring repository:

```
interface MyNodesRepository : Neo4jRepository<MyNode, Long>
```

Then, when I save a node into the DB via this repository it is empty, without any properties:

```
val node = MyNode(null, "name 1", "lorem ipsum")
myNodesRepository.save(node)
```

after the `save(node)` call, the `node.dbId` is set to the Neo4j's internal id  i.e. it is null before `save()` and has a value afterwards. I can also see the node in the Neo4j browser, but it does not have name and description properties.

After that, when I try to load all nodes the call crashes with `InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException` because it cannot deserialize/map the nodes with null/missing name and description:

```
val allNodes = myNodesRepository.findAll()
```

If I add a custom save method to my repository, where I manually create the node with CQL query, then everything works.

```
interface MyNodesRepository : Neo4jRepository<MyNode, Long> {
    @Query(
        "MERGE (mn:MyNode {name:{name}})\n" +
            "ON CREATE SET m += {description:{description}}"
    )
    fun customSave(@Param("name") name: String, @Param("description") description: String)
}
```

Now the `findAll()` loads my newly created and/or updated nodes.

I am using `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-neo4j:2.1.6.RELEASE` and this is inside a Spring Boot CLI application so no web server and RestControllers.

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:** This is now solved in Neo4j OGM 3.1.13

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:** This is now solved in Neo4j OGM 3.1.13 and the workaround below is not needed anymore.

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

After few days of debugging it looks like there is a bug in Neo4j OGM for Kotlin data classes where it does not save `val` properties -- both in data classes and normal classes. So change from `val` properties:

```
@NodeEntity
data class MyNode (
    @Id @GeneratedValue var dbId: Long? = null,
    @Index(unique = true) val name: String,
    val description: String
)
```

to all `var` properties:

```
@NodeEntity
data class MyNode (
    @Id @GeneratedValue var dbId: Long? = null,
    @Index(unique = true) var name: String,
    var description: String
)
```

works. Now both saving and loading works, but it is not idiomatic Kotlin.

So at least we have a workaround.